# What does ||{} mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I'm working on a project using Easel JS. Opened up the Easel file and the very first line of code confused me:

```
this.createjs = this.createjs||{};
```

I know that createjs is invoked when you're setting up your canvas or, for example, creating a bitmap to add to the canvas. But I don't understand the syntax of this line - assign this.createjs or (what I guess is) a blank object to this.createjs?

Comment: if this.createjs object does not exist initialize this.createjs as an object… is what it means..

Comment: It means: If this.createjs isn't undefined then use this.createjs otherwise use an empty object.

Comment: if this.createjs is falsy (undefined, false, etc) it will be replaced by empty object.

Comment: You can consider this as setting a default value for `this.createjs`. The default value is an empty object `{}` if an existing value does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
this.createjs = this.createjs||{};
```

If `this.createjs` is not available/ any `falsy` value then you are assigning `{}` empty object to `this.createjs`.

It's more like,

```
var a, 
    b;

b = a || 5;
```

Since `a` is not having any value currently, `5` will be assigned to `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. This ensures that if `this.createjs` doesn't already exist, an empty object is assigned to it. The `||` is an or operator - if `this.createjs` on the left-hand-side evaluates to [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), it will assign the right-hand-side instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.createjs = this.createjs||{};
```

If this.createjs is falsy, this.createjs will be a new empty object

You could have replace it by

```
if (!this.createjs){
     this.createjs = {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`||` means `or`.
In that context means `this.createjs` equals if exists/not null/defined `this.createjs` other way `{}`